# PXFormula and SumCalc not calculating correctly (doubling value of field)

Tags: acumatica

Where does the code that makes a PX Formula work exist? I at first assumed it was a SQL Trigger, but I can't seem to find it there.  This is why I ask....

I've added a custom field to the SO, called usrSpeedyTotalExt2. I'm trying to get that to sum the SOLine.CuryLineAmt. I added attributes to the SOLine DAC to append the follwing:

```
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<SOOrderExt.usrSpeedyTotalExt2>))]
```

This seemed to work, but know I'm fining that the value is consistently twice as high as it should be. I've got a second field that's doing the exact same thing.

What's increasingly odd is that I had the same problem with the field, and I thought I had done something wrong so I deleted the PXFormula, created a new field and then added the PX Formula to populate the new field. As such, there shouldn't be any code populating the old field, but strangely it's populated, so there must b e some business logic that's stuck and somehow still populating it.

Any thoughts on how I track this down?

Comment: > Where does the code that makes a PX Formula work exist?
- Very very deep and likely peppered all around in multiple files. 
- I doubt looking at that code will bring any insight, it is highly generic.

Comment: There's two approach you can take, search a similar pattern with Source Code page and compare it with your current implementation or drop the attribute and compute the value in a graph event like RowSelected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I figured out the problem...I think that the code may have been imported and published on more than one company, then published from the proper company to multiple tenants.

My fix was to go to the live company, un-publish all, then go back to the company the customizations live in and publish to the appropriate tenants. It would appear that now I'm only getting the proper totals. IDK how that might have happened, but at least it appears to be fixed.

Comment: Customizations are currently for an instance so publish in one company/tenant would apply for all company/tenant. The only thing in a publish that is per tenant is something that would insert into the database such as sitemaps, generic inquires, etc. The formulas are always posting the difference and do not self adjust on each update of the child values. So once the parent sumcalc value is off it will remain off.

Comment: Brendan is right, maybe a glitch occurred and you had 2 instance of the customization compiled in memory. IISReset along with re-publishing a single project could have fixed the issue if this is what happened.